# Jersey SLF4j log level

Tags: java, log4j, jersey, slf4j, java.util.logging

I'm trying to get Jersey to log to slf4j (backed by log4j).  I have

```
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

but the Jersey code uses `isLoggable` to check if the level is enabled before logging.  I've attempted to set the level on the root JUL logger using

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.ALL)
```

but this results in a `java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord`.  I've read lots of posts about this issue but haven't seen a solution.

SLF4j API 1.7.5
log4j 1.2.17
Java 7

Comment: what you're trying to achieve? To bypass all `isLoggable` checks?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't clear.  JUL defaults the log level to INFO and the SLF4jBridgeHandler doesn't propagate the level to the logging implementation (log4j in my case).  So the problem is that if is set my log4j config to DEBUG, then I still don't see any DEBUG logs because the isLoggable JUL check fails because it's still checking against the JUL level (INFO).